# Raw image data to WSQ compressed Image in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I Want to compress raw image data to wsq compressed in my iOS App, I refered https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/nist-biometric-image-software-nbis which has c library but it is creating library for linux and macOS is there any way use these library in iOS or is there any library which converts raw image data to wsq compressed image

I have tried using libnbis.a which is created by nist library in my iOS project but i am getting "lnbis(libz.a) is not an object file (not allowed in a library)" Error

Comment: You would be better off checking out Aware SDK for that from https://www.aware.com/biometrics/ The WSQ (Wavelet scalar quantization algorithm) can be used on other platforms too besides Linux an MacOS.

Comment: @JosephMuithi, Thank you, I have come across aware.com/biometrics it seems paid one is there any SDK which is available for free?

Comment: I do not know of any other SDK that is opensource that supports WSQ on iOS.